# jquery calculations

Tags: jquery

```
var res_available= parseInt($("#cur_lumber").val()) + parseInt($("#cur_clay").val()) + parseInt($("#cur_iron").val()) + parseInt($("#cur_crop").val());
var res_reserved= parseInt($("#reserve_lumber").val()) + parseInt($("#reserve_clay").val()) + parseInt($("#reserve_iron").val()) + parseInt($("#reserve_crop").val());
res_availabe= res_available-res_reserved;
alert(res_available);
```

The alert does not show the correct answer. It shows the value of res_available before i subtracted res_reserved from it.

I am not being able to find where i am going wrong, am missing the error. PLease could someone help.

Comment: Are you sure `res_reserved` is `> 0`?

Comment: Can you confirm the values of all the other variables? My first thought when you said "...it shows the value before i subtracted..." I thought res_reserved must be 0!

Comment: Without knowing what the input is we can't do much to help.

Comment: yes. I had input 100 in all the 4 text boxes from where res_reserved is being calculated. When i had put an alert to display the res_reserved, it was displaying the correct answer. But the subtraction doesn't seem to take place.

Comment: Always give a radix when using `parseInt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `res_available` in your code:

```
res_availabe= res_available-res_reserved;
```

should be

```
res_available -= res_reserved;
```

Comment: thankyou... wy doesn't html show error report like c, c++ or java... :( debugging is much easier there

Comment: why?--------------------

Comment: it's not technically an error, you were just creating a new global variable that you then weren't using. Your browser's console will show errors when there is an actual error.

Comment: @debal: You would have gotten an error if you used `'use strict';`!

Comment: @FelixKling good point, and [a reference for those interested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FStrict_mode)  I'm almost afraid to use strict mode in my code... lol